# Codeigniter: unable to send email

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a "Contact Us" page, where if users submit the form. Then email should go to the specified email.

After submiting the form i am getting the Success message ,but i am not seeing any email in my inbox/spam.

*I am testing on my **live server**.*

Pelase help me to solve my problem.

My code:

```
<?php
        if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

        class contact extends CI_Controller  {
            public function __construct()
            {
                parent:: __construct(); 
                $this->load->helper('url');
                $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->library('session');
                $this->load->library('email');
                $this->load->model('shopmodel');
                $this->load->model('contactusmodel');
                $this->load->library('form_validation'); 
            } 

            function index()
            {
                 $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters(' <li  class="errorlist">', '</li>')->set_rules('fullname', 'Name','trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
                 $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li  class="errorlist">', '</li>')->set_rules('countryname', 'Country','trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
                 $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li  class="errorlist">', '</li>')->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
                 $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li  class="errorlist">', '</li>')->set_rules('contactdetails', 'Contact Details','trim|required|min_length[40]|max_length[2000]|xss_clean');
                 $data=$this->contactusmodel->contactusmodel();
                 $data["query"] = $this->shopmodel->getshopdetailsById(199);//taking data as shop id 199 

                  if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
                  {  
                        $data['ffullname']['value'] = $this->input->post('fullname');
                        $data['fcountryname']['value'] =$this->input->post('email');
                        $data['femail']['value'] = $this->input->post('countryname'); 
                        $data['fcontactdetails']['value'] =$this->input->post('contactdetails'); 
                        $this->load->view('contact/contact',$data);  
                  }

                  else if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
                  {
                      $name=$this->input->post('fullname');
                      $sendersemail=$this->input->post('email');
                      $fromcountry=$this->input->post('countryname');
                      $message=$this->input->post('contactdetails'); 

                      $config = Array(
                        'protocol' => 'smtp',
                                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                                'smtp_port' => 465,
                                'smtp_user' => 'ashutosh10g@gmail.com',
                                'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxx',
                                'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                                'charset' => 'utf-8',
                                'wordwrap' => TRUE

                     );

                       $this->load->library('email', $config);
                       $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
                        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
                        $email_body ="<div>hello world</div>";
                        $this->email->from('ashutosh10g@gmail.com', 'ddd');

                        $list = array('ashutosh10g@gmail.com');
                        $this->email->to($list);
                        $this->email->subject('Testing Email');
                        $this->email->message($email_body);

                        $this->email->send();
                        echo $this->email->print_debugger(); 
                  }
                  else{
                      $this->load->view('contact/contact',$data);  
                  }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

What output i am getting is:

```
    [code]
    Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail
    From: "ddd" 
    Return-Path: 
    Reply-To: "ashutosh10g@gmail.com" 
    X-Sender: ashutosh10g@gmail.com
    X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
    X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
    Message-ID: <513e1456185d4@gmail.com>
    Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_513e1456185e3"


    =?utf-8?Q?Testing_Email?=
    This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
    Your email application may not support this format.

    --B_ALT_513e1456185e3
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

    hello world


    --B_ALT_513e1456185e3
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

    <div>hello world</div>

    --B_ALT_513e1456185e3--
```

Comment: Everything here looks fine to me. Problem is probably elsewhere. Either incorrect email address, or the server may be having issues sending email in general. Check your server logs for errors. I hope that's not your real SMTP password.

Comment: @NicholasPickering  The email & password which i mention in my application is 100% correct.  But i don't know why mail is not sending after geting the success message as show above.   Or else is there any other way of sending mail in codeigniter? i will try that also. Please help

Comment: Could you show your config/email.php ?

Comment: i do not have email.php in my config folder. I have Email.php in my System/libraries/Email.php

Comment: @Ashutosh you should not post your password for anything on StackOverflow - You could give hackers access to your account. Always replace it with "password" or something that is obviously not your real password.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are experimenting a relaying error somtimes the Google Server don't accept relay mail form one MTA to another inbox. Try to test to establish an SMTP dialog to your server an try to send the mail. Here is a simple SMTP dialog example:

http://www.soi.wide.ad.jp/class/20000009/slides/11/6.html

Try to send a mail if the server sends a relay error you should try with another SMTP server. If not maybe is a missconfiguration of your php.

But in my experience gmail always deny the relaying mail for spam and security reasons if the MTA is not a trusted agent.

Another reason may be that you don't have correctly configure DNS Servers and your MTA cannot find the MX Records. Example y your MTA is sendmail it notifies php tha the mail was send succesfully but if you look into sendmail logs you can find that the host is unreachable.